# Can a .NET web application be host on dedicated linux server with static IP and run this web app as a web site?

Tags: asp.net, .net, mysql, linux

I am working on a project which is a web based in which it has three different modules. For this whole project I am using a dedicated server with static IP which is a linux server with MySQL as a database.

Now my query is, in my project I am using a web and desktop application which connects to my server. Now my web application is integrated with my company website which is done in .NET
Is it possible to host my website in my dedicated server which is a linux version?

Could some one tell me which is the best way to run my whole project in a better way.

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a remote MySQL server instance from your .NET application, you need to ensure that any network routing and firewall rules let you through.  You must ensure that the application server can reach the MySQL server on the 'listening' port (probably 3306).

Ideally you will have both the database server and application server in close proximity and on the same local network, otherwise there is no problem in this hosting architecture at all.  Web applications and databases often require different tuning optimisations and for redundancy purposes it is also good practice to separate them out.  Of course, you only have redundancy if you have more than one application server and more than one database server.